# Python Killing a Subprocess

Tags: python, linux

Python 2.7, Ubuntu 16.04

We have a proprietary mathematical package we purchased that we use for calculations. We are trying to build a process that kills the subprocess of that package after running for 10 seconds.

The solution below kills the `do_math()` function after 10 seconds as expected. However the `solve` launches a sub process with it's own pid. So, doing a `ps aux` shows that it runs under its own name, and not under the `python` name.

Is there any way to track and kill a pid that has been launched this way in python?

```
def do_math():
    status = solve() #launches the package

#Start function as a process
k = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_math)
k.start()

# Wait for 10 seconds or until process finishes
k.join(10)

# If thread is still active
if k.is_alive():
    print k.pid
    os.kill(k.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: Any directional advice is appreciated as well if not an answer

Comment: Killing a child that's spawned its own children will orphan those grandchildren. (I think this is explained in the docs.) Depending on how that child code in `solve` is designed, this could mean a few different things, but none of them are things you can easily work around without walking the process tree to find the grandchildren before killing the child.

Comment: One more thing: If you purchased this package, surely it comes with some support? Have you tried asking them the recommended way to terminate a `solve`? Or asking them to add one, if they never thought of that?

Comment: Yeah, we tried :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `solve` function is doing something nasty that you can't change, there is no easy or clean way to do this.

One possibility is to spawn the child in its own group and then nuke the group… but that's not trivial to manage with `multiprocessing`, and it may not even work depending on how `solve` launches the grandchildren.

An even hackier way, but probably both easier and more likely to work, is to manually walk the child's process tree to find and kill any grandchildren either before or after killing the child. The simplest way to do that is probably a third-party library like [`psutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil). It would look something like this:

```
# Shortly after launching k
p = psutil.Process(k.pid)

# Later, right before killing k
for child in p.children():
    p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

If you want to kill them after the child (I assume there's a reason you're sending `SIGINT` instead of `SIGTERM`, so this might matter), you'll want to copy `p.children()` first before killing `k`.

Comment: Yeah, had to do pretty much this since the `solve` function is real nasty as you've said. Should your answer be `p.kill()` instead of `p.kill(signal.SIGINT)` though, I got a too many args error running it with the `SIGINT` inside?

Comment: @HoosierCoder Yeah, I forgot that `kill` doesn't take an argument. But if you had a good reason to send SIGINT, you don't want to just send SIGKILL instead because it happens to be the default. Use [`send_signal`](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.send_signal). The docs for `psutil` are very nice (and include recipes for things like killing a whole tree of children, doing graceful kills where you send a SIGKILL then wait then SIGKILL, etc.); don't just blindly shotgun things instead of looking.

Comment: Should you take the `signal.SIGINT` out from the answer so it doesn't trip up anyone reading this?

Comment: @HoosierCoder I already changed it to use `send_signal`, and hopefully anyone who has this problem and sees that the question was trying to send SIGINT will see that the answer does the same will know how to adapt it if they want to send SIGKILL or SIGTERM instead.

Comment: Oh, I see. Nice